# Pass current controller instance to modal service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service, controller, instance

I have a `CartController`, which, on `showCheckout`, does this:

```
    ModalService.showModal({
        templateUrl: '/Product/CartCheckout',
        controller: 'CartController'
}).then(function (modal) {
        ...
    });
```

This is based on [angularModalService.js](https://github.com/dwmkerr/angular-modal-service). I'm just passing the current controller because I wouldn't like to create a new controller just to handle the `Open()` and `Close()` of the modal dialog.

However, passing a controller just by name seems to instantiate a new instance of that controller. I want to pass the current instance of my controller to the service. I've tried:

```
   controller: $controller('CartController', $scope)
```

But I get `Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- CartController`. 
I've also tried:

```
  controller: $scope.ctrl
```

But it just seems to be ignored without throwing any errors, nothing happens and the dialog is never shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed it by modifying AngularModalService.js as follows:

```
var modalScope = $rootScope.$new();
```

to

```
var modalScope = options.controllerScope || $rootScope.$new();
```

And then calling it as:

```
        ModalService.showModal({
            templateUrl: '/Product/CartCheckout',
            controller: 'CartController',
            controllerScope : $scope
```

Answer (score 0):

scope: Optional. If provided, the modal controller will use a new scope as a child of scope (created by calling scope.$new()) rather than a new scope created as a child of $rootScope.

use ***scope: $scope***   ("to enforce the current scope controller to be the parent") rather than 
***controllerScope : $scope***  which enforces the $rootScope to be the parent.
and access your objects via $scope.$parent.YOUROBJECTS